# I'm running python 2.7 on windows. I'm trying to install packages using pip, but keep getting syntax errors. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

[image][image]

I'm trying to install wikipedia's basic python package with pip, and I keep getting syntax errors. I'm using pip through the python command line. Attached a screen shot of what I'm trying to do here. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You do not need the `$` character, that is just the prompt charcter for linux,  like `>>>` for IDLE. And `sudo` is a linux command, not windows.

Comment: Why are you trying to run `pip` in the Python interpreter?!

Comment: I tried sudo and the $ sign after regular did not work

Comment: @JonGor Read my comment above, neither of those apply to windows.

Comment: It appears that `pip` is **not** correctly installed for the command line. How precisely did you install it?  Please stop posting screenshots, it's much better to provide code-formatted text.

Comment: OK, sure. I copied the text from https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py to my python interpreter ( Pycharm) and ran it. I got a "successfully installed" notification.

Comment: The Python interpreter and the command line are two very different things.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/4750806/3001761

Answer (score 2):

pip must be run from the command shell, not the python shell.

Answer (score 2):

run it from a `cmd` prompt not a python interpreter:

```
 pip install wikipedia
```

If you don't have pip installed which you don't seem to have then  download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and run `python get-pip.py`

Comment: At which directory should I be to run it?

Comment: @JonGor, have you installed pip?

Comment: I think so, I can see it at C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages, and also when I run import pip on my python shell it recognizes the command.

Comment: @JonGor if you're in the Python shell, run `exit()`, **then** run `pip`.

Comment: @JonGor, forget about python. Run pip  from a cmd prompt but **install** it first using get-pip.py as in my answer

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, jonrsharpe - I added a screen shot where I tried to run it from a cmd shell. It still didn't work. I think I have installed it already - how can I make sure that its properly installed?

Comment: @JonGor, just install using get-pip.py it will take a few seconds

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, could you be a little more specific as to what that means? I am new to python, so I do not understand what installing it using get-pip.py means.

Comment: @JonGor, have you looked at my answer? I provided the link and how to install it

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I downloaded and ran the file. It automatically ran through my interpreter (Pycharm), and I got the message "Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages"

Comment: what error do you get running pip from a command shell?

Comment: "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: have you added `C:\Python27\Scripts` to your path?

Comment: @JonGor you need to add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to your `PATH` environment variable. Then, restart `cmd` and it'll work.

Comment: Thank you both!! That's what was missing - the C:\Python27\Scripts

Comment: @JonGor, no worries.

Answer (score -2):

You could also download the python install package, extract it, navigate to install.py in CMD and do "python install.py install"